# How to check if either select box or text inputs are empty with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 2 select boxes and a text input. On change of any of those 3 elements I want to run a check to see if any of the elements are empty(no value) and then change a variable. Here's what I have tried so far:

```js
var emptyFields = true;

var inputs = $('input[type="text"], select').on('keyup change', function() {

  inputs.each(function() {
    var elm = $(this),
    val = elm.val();

    if ((val != '0' && elm.is('select')) || (val != '' && elm.is('input'))) {
      emptyFields = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  $('.info span').text(emptyFields);
});
```

```css
.info {
margin-top:20px;
}
span {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option selected disabled>SELECT AN OPTION</option>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>

<select>
<option selected disabled>SELECT AN OPTION</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
<option>Six</option>
</select>

<input type="text" />

<div class="info">Empty fields? <span></span></div>
```

The issue I am having now is that the variable is changing to `false` even before all 3 elements have a value. If you are completing the elements from left to right, the variable should not return `false` until you've entered a character into the `text input` after making a selection in each `select` box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem: Once you set the variable to `false` during a check, you never change it back to `true` in future checks. You should use a local variable, which you initialize each time you call the function.

Second problem: You have your check backwards. Since you want to show `true` if *any* of the fields are empty, you need to initialize the variable to `false`, then set it to `true` when you find an empty field.

```js
var inputs = $('input[type="text"], select').on('keyup change', function() {
  var emptyFields = false;
  inputs.each(function() {
    var elm = $(this),
    val = elm.val();

    if ((val == '0' && elm.is('select')) || (val == '' && elm.is('input'))) {
      emptyFields = true;
      return false;
    }
  });

  $('.info span').text(emptyFields);
});
```

```css
.info {
margin-top:20px;
}
span {
font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
<option selected disabled>SELECT AN OPTION</option>
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>Three</option>
</select>

<select>
<option selected disabled>SELECT AN OPTION</option>
<option>Four</option>
<option>Five</option>
<option>Six</option>
</select>

<input type="text" />

<div class="info">Empty fields? <span></span></div>
```